# Where can I find cheap domains for sale?

Tags: domains, marketing

I have been settling on the `.biz` namespace for some time because I cannot find any available `.com`'s. However, I run a computer repair business and someone tried to sell me `motherboardrepair.com` for $100. This is a good deal for me, unfortunately I do not do motherboard repair.

Is there a website where I can signup for emails of offers like these?

**Clarification**: I do not have a specific name in mind. I want to join a mailing list to spectate what offers are out there. Does such a list exist and is not spammed so much that I wouldn't want to join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy, among others, can set you up on waiting lists for domains. You can also pay a premium to attempt to snipe a domain from expiry, though this is not a guarantee.

As an aside, I can't imagine a `.com` that could suite you isn't available as long as you're keeping it unique to your business. Granted, things with `motherboard`, `processor`, `hard drive` (and any other PC component and/or variation) are probably accounted for, but what's wrong with `mybusinessname.com`/`my-business-name.com`?

Granted, you can acquire business from online marketing but you'll need the content on the site to do the talking. Admittedly URL text is a heavy-hitter on the SEO rank, but placing information and a well-formatted website within that domain can score higher points. Also, it allows people to find you easier by name for when you build your reputation up (otherwise the user gets hits from google, yellow pages, etc. describing just your location).

Just my $0.02

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that. I mean what does yahoo mean anyway? But I remember it. However, most my business customers are found online as I do not have a physical office.

Comment: @unixman83: Then use adwords, facebook advertising, etc. to draw them in. Having `broken-pc.com` may help with people searching for just that, but it doesn't speak anything for the reputation, customer support or pricing. Think about this: "Dell"/"HP" rank highly when searching for new PCs, yet neither have any "related" keywords in the domain name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the new ".co" domain?

Comment: I just heard about people doing that yesterday. Kinda makes me mad though. And is a recipe for a lawsuit if you take someone's domain that's got importance.